# How to find if a key is present in an array - Typescript - Microsoft flows

Tags: typescript, power-automate

I have multiple users and I want to filter them based on their office location
I get the location with a flow "Search for users (V2)" which returns an array of information about each user that includes ID, Email, Country .. etc

Some of them do not have all of these info, in my case they don't (Office location) at all, which will cause the flow to show an error

This is my flow

[image: Flow]

This is the result
[image: result]

and error
[image: condition error]

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to why you're using a `Condition` action with a `first()` function straight after your `Search for users` call, that doesn't match the description on your issue.

If it were me, I'd be using the `Filter array` action to get that list broken down as need be and then you can work with it from there.

In my test below, you can see that I'm filtering based on the term **Head Office** in the returned array.

[image: Flow]

I have 3 users that it pulls back and two have the `OfficeLocation` property set to **Head Office**.

**Before Filter**

```
[
  {
    "Id": "c9692d85-ae00-470f-8544-4ded06082d59",
    "AccountEnabled": true,
    "BusinessPhones": [],
    "DisplayName": "Automation",
    "Mail": "automation@somewhere.com",
    "MailNickname": "automation",
    "OfficeLocation": "Head Office",
    "UserPrincipalName": "automation@somewhere.com"
  },
  {
    "Id": "8ddf4a13-fa28-4c76-8a79-dfcc680b57b9",
    "AccountEnabled": true,
    "BusinessPhones": [
      "4251001000"
    ],
    "DisplayName": "Joe Bloggs",
    "GivenName": "Joe",
    "Mail": "joe.bloggs@somewhere.com",
    "MailNickname": "joe.bloggs",
    "Surname": "Bloggs",
    "UserPrincipalName": "joe.bloggs@somewhere.com"
  },
  {
    "Id": "9d903297-2777-48d8-beb3-95e4e9ad2851",
    "AccountEnabled": true,
    "BusinessPhones": [],
    "DisplayName": "Jane Doe",
    "GivenName": "Jane",
    "Mail": "jane.doe@somewhere.com",
    "MailNickname": "jane.doe",
    "OfficeLocation": "Head Office",
    "Surname": "Doe",
    "UserPrincipalName": "jane.doe@somewhere.com"
  }
]
```

**After Filter**

```
[
  {
    "Id": "c9692d85-ae00-470f-8544-4ded06082d59",
    "AccountEnabled": true,
    "BusinessPhones": [],
    "DisplayName": "Automation",
    "Mail": "automation@somewhere.com",
    "MailNickname": "automation",
    "OfficeLocation": "Head Office",
    "UserPrincipalName": "automation@somewhere.com"
  },
  {
    "Id": "9d903297-2777-48d8-beb3-95e4e9ad2851",
    "AccountEnabled": true,
    "BusinessPhones": [],
    "DisplayName": "Jane Doe",
    "GivenName": "Jane",
    "Mail": "jane.doe@somewhere.com",
    "MailNickname": "jane.dow",
    "OfficeLocation": "Head Office",
    "Surname": "Doe",
    "UserPrincipalName": "jane.doe@somewhere.com"
  }
]
```